# Flutter Timer.Periodic stops during Sleep Mode, how can I re-enter into the logic loop using Lifecycle Code?

Tags: ios, flutter, timer, lifecycle

I'm still pretty new and I had a bug in my code wherein, if the device went to sleep during it's normal function, (while it was waiting for a response from a server) then the entire app basically just freezes, and doesn't come back.

Now I didn't have any lifecycle code in there at the time, so I understand that it's the solution, but how can I handle that specifically?

(Life cycle code)

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
      super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
      if(state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
        /*
        What information Needs to be saved?
        */

      } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
        /*
        What information needs to be restored, and how to do so if it's not 
        instantly obvious?
        */
      }
  }
```

(Code with Timer that is giving the issue)

```
  //Timer to check Status of Trip, and take action based of Trip Status

  Timer.periodic(timerInterval, (ztimer)  { // Timer to constantly refresh information
    counter++;
    if ((counter >= 120) && (switchedScreens) && (splashActive)){ 
      ztimer.cancel();
      cancelReq();
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
    getInfo(sessionID); // Get Request Info
    info = updateInfo(); // Refresh info in program.
    if (info != null) {
    reqStatus = info['status'];
      if (dispatchVerified == true) { // Check to see if the call has been verified
        if (reqStatus != previousReqStatus) { // Check to see if the Status of the call has changed
          previousReqStatus = reqStatus;
          if ((reqStatus == 'deleted') || (reqStatus == 'complete') || (reqStatus == 'noCall')) { // If the request status would end the call, do so
            ztimer.cancel();
            if (splashActive) { //if deleted by server, would still be on Splash Screen
              splashActive = false;
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
            cancelReq();
          } else if (reqStatus == 'accepted') { // If accepted, switch back from Splash Page
            if (splashActive) {
              splashActive = false;
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }        
            reqPosition = new LatLng(info['cab'][0]['latitude'], info['req'][0]['longitude']);  // add and update the position of the request for the marker
            if (!addedReqPosition) {
              addedReqPosition = true;
              addReqPosition();
            }
          } else if (reqStatus == 'canceled'){ // If Call was cancelled, but on Splash Page, ensure it's removed.
            ztimer.cancel();
            if (splashActive) {
              splashActive = false;
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
            cancelReq();          
          } else if (reqStatus == 'editing') {
              dispatchVerified = false;
              splashActive = true;
              stream = new DataStream();
              Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => SplashPage(stream: stream)));
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (reqStatus == 'editing') {
        } else if ((reqStatus == 'unassigned') || (reqStatus == 'pendingConfirmation')) { // Request has now been verified
          if (switchedScreens) {
            dispatchVerified = true;
            switchedScreens = false;
            stream.dataSink.add(true);
          }
        } else if (reqStatus == 'deleted'){ // If Call was Deleted by Server, reset state of app.
          ztimer.cancel();
          if (splashActive) {
            splashActive = false;
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
          cancelReq();
        }
      }
    }
    if (booking == false) {
      ztimer.cancel();
    }
    mapState.setState(() {});
  });
```

What can I try next?

Comment: you can use [flutter isolates](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) for background concurrent execution while the app is in pause state. In the resume state, you can contact the same isolate to check the status of your service call.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  I looked into it, and find the documentation a little confusing as to how to set-up.  If you have any additional information about them, that would be great.  Either way, thank you!  I'm not 100% sure I can use it, but I'll try.

Comment: I haven't used them, just a thought came to my mind, you can try few medium blogs. I hope that works.